# Timezones and cron

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a MySQL database containing details of shops in different time zones. The timezone of each store is stored in iana format and the MySQL datetimes are stored in UTC.

I wish to execute some php code at the end of the day for each shop.

This is how I am thinking to approach this but is there a better way?

1. Set a cron to run hourly at xx:59:59.
2. Get the current date at the top of the php script. Is the script guaranteed to get the correct date at 23:59:59?
3. Use SQL query to return all shops that are at the end of the current day. I'm not sure how to check this in the query?
4. Perform the end of the day processing on those stores.

Comment: i thinks thats no a bad plan. Depending on store numbers etc. you could have a separate cron job per timezone; which had a list of sites to process

Comment: Do you want to run the script on each shop server or on the server containing the details?

Comment: On the single server containing the details.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can run an hourly cron job any time you wish.
2. Why do you need the date here? You wrote that you're interested in the servers, which are at 23:59:59 localtime, so time is relevant, I think, not the date. Also, if your details server is *very* busy, your script might run too late and get the next day's date.
3. If IANA time zone format means offset to UTC, you could simply look for shops having a timezone like

   ```
   24 - current time(UTC) +/- DST
   ```

   Negative timezone offsets work similar, e.g. `24 + offset`. So timezone offset `-01:00` would become `+23:00`
4. Nothing to say here.

Comment: Data is constantly created in the database the right up to the end of the day. I need to capture all of that data right up to the end of the day. Then I do some processing, add a summary of that data to a second table and delete the data in the first table for the current day for that store. Maybe it is better to run the cron at the beginning of the day and process the previous day?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter that much. But if you need the whole day up to the last second, doing it after the 24 hour period is preferred of course. But even then you don't need a date, but just the `00:00:00` `time()`stamp. With the range `now(0:00)-24 hours` up to `now(0:00)`, you have all relevant entries.